# laravel link up 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have 3 tables: 
`users, roles, permission` while two tables: `role_users` and `permission_role` are storing the `keys`

A users belongs to many `roles`. In `App\user.php`, i can retrieve the roles (i only retrieve one role is needed even the relationship is many)

```
public function roles()
{
    //return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

A roles has many permissions, but how can i retrieve the permissions via user?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: my situation has pivot table, the doc has no solution